# Is it possible to log queries only for one view in Django?

Tags: django

I know, that in settings, I can have `debug = True` and all SQL queries are logged.

But, I want to log all the SQL queries made by one specific view, before the response is returned.

How can I do this in Django 1.3 ?

Comment: As an aside; check out sentry for logging https://github.com/dcramer/sentry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by changing logging settings within context of specific view.

You still need to have `DEBUG` enabled:

> For performance reasons, SQL logging is only enabled when settings.DEBUG is set to True, regardless of the logging level or handlers that are installed.

... but you can modify configuration so that only queries by specific view(s) are logged.

Here's how it could be done:

1: In `settings.py` set django SQL logger (`django.db.backends`) level to `INFO` or higher and verify that it stopped recording SQL queries.

2.a. First line in your view to have SQL logging, set that logger level to `DEBUG`.  Last line, set it back to original value.  This is simplest way, but queries executed by middleware before/after view code don't get logged.

2.b. Write custom middleware to do the same thing before and after view processing.  If you place it first, all queries made by other middlewares will be also logged.

Note that this method is not thread safe, but since you only want this setup in development environment, this should not matter.

---

Django documentation "Logging" chapter:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/logging/

Python logging library reference:
http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html